# XSLT mapping values of attribute from range

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to xslt and i need your help.

My input xml file looks like this

```
<dataset>
    <item date="13days" />
    <item date="14days" />
    <item date="27days" />
</dataset>
```

And my output should look like this

```
<dataset>
    <item date="1week" />
    <item date="2week" />
    <item date="3week" />
</dataset>
```

Map would look like this:

```
0days<=1week<14days
14days<=2week<21days
21days<=3week<28days
```

For now i just know how to change specific date, but i need ranges. Here's my attempt.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<my:map>
<map>
<item from="13days" to="1week" />
<item from="14days" to="2week" />
<item from="27days" to="3week" />
</map>
</my:map>
<xsl:variable name="vMap" select="document('')/*/my:map/*/*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@maturity[. = document('')/*/my:map/*/*/@from]">
<xsl:attribute name="maturity">
<xsl:value-of select="$vMap[@from = current()]/@to"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Will the input file only ever contain "days"?

Comment: Yep. It always will be any number + 'days' etc. 128days, 3045days and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@date">
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring-before(., 'days')" />
    <xsl:attribute name="date">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$d &lt; 14">1week</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$d &lt; 21">2week</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$d &lt; 28">3week</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="@date">
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring-before(., 'days')" />
    <xsl:attribute name="date">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$d &lt; 14">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="floor($d div 7)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>week</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```